# Menu DropDown no CSS

Tags: css, css3, css-hover

Boa tarde Galera,

Como eu faço funcionar o dropdown no menu que criei?
   Esconder o dropdown do o que fazemos foi fácil, mas como eu faço ele aparecer com o mouse sobre a opção do "o que fazemos"?
   Tentei colocar um id e propriedade hover mas não funcionou...

```
<nav>
            <ul class="main_menu">
                <li><a href="#" class="li_principal">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="li_principal">Quem Somos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="li_principal">O que fazemos</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="li_secundario">Criação de WebSites</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="li_secundario">SEO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="li_secundario">Design Gráfico</a></li>                    
                        <li><a href="#" class="li_secundario">Hospedagem de Sites</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="li_secundario">Gerenciamento de Redes Sociais</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="li_secundario">Branding</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="li_secundario">E-mail Marketing</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="li_principal">Portifólio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="li_principal">Contato</a></li>                
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

meu css está desta forma:

```
.main_menu li{
    float:left;
}

.li_principal{
    float:left;
    font-size:30px;
    font-family:"Verdana";
    padding-left:25px;
    padding-right:25px;
    position:relative;
        left:500px;
    color:#499322;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#C0C0C0;
    border-top-left-radius: 10em;
    border-top-right-radius:10em;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10em;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10em;
    height:35px;
    opacity:0.85;
}

.li_secundario{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Põe no hover do li_principal:

```
li_principal:hover ~ ul { display: block }
```